# Civilization 6 under Wine on MacOS - cannot click "Continue"

Tags: macos, civilization-6, wine

I'm trying to run Civilization 6 under Wine on MacOS, Intel hardware.

I've installed Heroic launcher and am using Wine Crossover 22.1.1.

The game starts, but then I cannot click "Continue" button on the initial agreement, neither with mouse nor with keyboard.

I know that mouse input kinda works because I can interrupt the intro video with a mouse click.

#### Is it display resolution?

I've read somewhere that the problem may be that the screen resolution that mouse perceives is different from what is rendered, and so all UI is virtually off. I tried to fix the resolution.

The original resolution in `AppOptions.txt` was 1792x1120. Here's what I saw in the startup logs:

```
0024:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0000000000010046,{02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea},0): stub
info:  Setting timer interval to 1000 us
info:  Presenter: Actual swap chain properties:
info:    Format:       VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
info:    Present mode: VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR
info:    Buffer size:  1792x1120
info:    Image count:  2
info:    Exclusive FS: 1
[mvk-info] Created 2 swapchain images with initial size (1792, 1120) and contents scale 1.0 for screen Built-in Retina Display.
```

I've tried:

- editing `AppOptions.txt`, changing `RenderWidth` and `RenderHeight` to the display's resolution (3072 and 1920). The UI size has changed, but button still doesn't react to clicks;
- Changing `FullScreen` to `2` and `0`;
- Enabling `EnableArbitraryWindowSizing`;
- Changing DPI to 192 and to 226 (MacBook screen's native) in WineConfig.

#### Other ideas

##### Wayland (MoltenVK?) patch

[This topic on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/nuhnt8/civilization_vi_on_wine/) describes very similar problem on Linux. They fixed it by applying some patch from https://github.com/Kron4ek/Wine-Builds, but to my understanding, this is Wayland specific. I believe MacOS needs a completely different implementation, and it's hard to track it from there to the actual code that fixes the problem.

##### Corrupted configs

In [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/0/340412122410930845/), similar problem was solved by deleting everything in AppData/Firaxis. Didn't help me.

##### DPI scaling

In [this Steam thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289070/discussions/3/1471967615845806697/?l=latam), changing DPI scaling worked for someone. I may need to try other DPIs, but the most likely ones didn't help.

**What else can it be?**

P.S. I know that a native MacOS version exists. I already own Civ6 on iOS and would like to try it on computer, it's not worth buying another copy.